# How to go about integration of moogsoft with Sensu

Tags: alert, devops, sensu

I am exploring Moogsof's new tool and havent had much time looking into the tool. I have to integrate all alerts and events monitored on Sensu to Moogsoft's HTTP/ alert handler tool. I wanted to know if this must be done through:

-RESTful API or

-Plugin specific to this

-3rd party Open source tool for integration

I may be able to write node application on sensu so REST API seems to be plausable but if there is an easier way some guidance would help.

I have read the documentation and searched for ways. Moog.incident seems to be a tool for this. Any other source would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

Moogsoft can accept the events via rest, socket, email, snmp traps, or other methods. If you can format your events in a standard JSON format then rest will be the easiest.